# Are all linux drivers accessed through /dev?

Tags: file, linux-device-driver

It's my understanding that all linux drivers made to be accessed in userspace are required to present a device file. That is, as far as I'm aware, the only way to interact with a driver is through file I/O in the `/dev` directory.

Is this true? If not, what are the other methods, and do they all require file I/O?

Comment: No, it's not true. There are several possible IPC mechanisms between Linux kernel and user space. One of them is character or block device. Now, your homework is to google for the rest.

Comment: So I've googled. Character and block drivers are accessed through /dev or by /proc as files. I can't really seem to pinpoint any other methods. Can you at least give me a name?

Comment: I did give you enough key words in previous comment, I'm not going to do your homework ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its not the case for network drivers!!!

It doesnt have a node in /dev/
network driver is opened / closed using ifconfig command.
configuration is done by ifonfig/ethtool.
and rest is done with network stack.

Other ways to communicate with device drivers from userspace:

> ```
> - /proc 
> - /sysfs 
> - netlink sockets
> - udev 
> - ioctl
> ```